# Redirection to canvas page after getting access token

Tags: facebook

I have recieved the access token from Facebook on my redirection page. Also saved it in session state. I just want to redirect back to canvas url (http://apps.facebook.com/example) from my redirection page. Is there anyway other then redirecting to the hardcoded canvas url.

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify what is `redirection page` ?

You can redirect from canvas url to canvas page by:

```
    <script>
    if (window.location == window.top.location)   //checking if framed
       window.location.replace('http://apps.facebook.com/exampe');
    <script>
```